# click function not showing more records

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, onclicklistener

### Project

I'm updating an Infinite Scroll ajax script to provide a `view more` href.

### Status:

First portion of the function is working correct...loading.gif shows, table is filled with LIMIT of 15 rows and loading.gif hides

### Issue

Click on the `view more` hyperlink is not being recognised...still responding as a normal `href="#"`

### populateRecords.js

**Note:** to hopefully reduce confusion, I've replaced the content of the 2nd function and ajax call with a simple `alert('');` for testing the click action.

```
var ajax_array = [];
var ajax_index = 0;
$(function () {
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "populateRecords.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#records').html(response);
        }
    });
    $("#viewmore_records").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Howsit?!');

        });
});
```

### records_manager.php

I've tried with populateRecords.js directly under (in the body)

```
    <img id='loading' src='../media/images/loading.gif'>
    <div id="records" cellspacing="0">
    </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../media/js/populateRecords.js?<?php echo date("dmyhis");?>"></script>
```

...as well as in the header...
Neither worked.

### #viewmore_records

<< View More >> is echo'd at the end of the string when the ajax rows load is complete.

Comment: Is the alert working?

Comment: are you loading the `view more` link dynamically?

Comment: @Anubhav alert is not triggering

Comment: @JosanIracheta view more link is hard coded

Comment: please make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the view_more link is loaded via ajax. Then try binding click event on ajax success as below.

```
var ajax_array = [];
var ajax_index = 0;
$(function () {
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "populateRecords.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#records').html(response);
            $("#viewmore_records").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              alert('Howsit?!');    
            });
        }
    });


});
```